# apache eaccelerator build php version

Tags: php, apache, magento, ubuntu, eaccelerator

I'm trying to get eAccelerator 0.9.6.1 installed to speed up my Magento site.

Pretty vanilla install per the directions here: 
http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_eAccelerator_In_Ubuntu_Server

Unfortunately, php -v does not show eAccelerator, and apache error log shows on restart after install:

```
[eAccelerator] This build of "eAccelerator" was compiled for PHP version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7. Rebuild it for your PHP version (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8) or download precompiled binaries.
```

/usr/bin/php-config shows

```
version="5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8"
```

make test says

```
PHP         : /usr/bin/php
PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
ZEND_VERSION: 2.3.0
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux libatio 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:04:05 UTC 2012 i686
```

phpinfo shows eAccelerator section with nothing enabled.
eAccelerator control.php shows no data.

What am I missing here? Seems I am compiling for the correct php, but apache disagrees?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No secret here except repeated reinstall with another copy of the same distro, although in the meantime I also installed Zend Optimizer and IonCube php loader.

Cheers ,
C